# How to print out menu names in the foreach loop?

Tags: loop, php

I have three different menus in the footer of my site. I have called them in the footer.php file with

```
 <?php
      $footerList = array("Footer", "Footer1", "Footer2");

        foreach ($footerList as $idx=>$footer) { 
           wp_nav_menu(array(

                'menu'               => $footer,
                'theme_location'     => 'footer',
                'container'          => 'div',
                'container_class'    => 'footer-links-content',

            ));
        }
    ?>
```

Is there any way I can print out names of the each menu using this foreach loop? Or some other way? I have tried `'before'` but it's displaying after every link. I need to have it on top of the links. [image: top of the links]

Comment: I could make this work with Custom Post Types and in the editor I could write some links, and then call them in the while loop with `<?php the_content(); ?>` but that's not user friendly. Still looking....